# Kotlin FirestorePagingAdapter with algolia

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore, firebaseui, algolia

I have this adapter in kotlin for firebase, to search a project with category it works to filter projects by category, but i want to search by title, searching i found algolia for fonetic search, i created an accound and indexed all projects but i cant use this to replace the projects on the recicler view because algolia returns me an json i don't know how to filter by title any suggestions ?
here is the adapter im using

```
class ProjectListAdapter( options : FirestorePagingOptions<ProjectEntity>, private val onItemClick : OnViewItemClickedListener ) : FirestorePagingAdapter<ProjectEntity, ProjectHolder>(options){
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ProjectHolder {
    val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
        .inflate(R.layout.item_project_creator, parent, false)

    return ProjectHolder(view)
}

override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ProjectHolder, position: Int, model: ProjectEntity) {
    holder.setProjectTitle(model.title)
    holder.setProjectSubtitle(model.subtitle)
    holder.setProjectCategory(model.category)
    holder.setProjectGoal(model.goal)
    holder.setProjectImage(model.image, model.creatorEmail)


    holder.getCardLayout().setOnClickListener {
        onItemClick.onViewItemDetail(model)
    }
  }
}
```

`this is the filter by category im using i would like to do something like that for the fonetic search`

```
private fun filterAllProjectsByCategory(){ allProjectListAdapter.stopListening() val categorySearch = binding.spinnerFilterCategory.selectedItem.toString() var query = db.collection("ideas").whereEqualTo("category", categorySearch)    
val config = PagingConfig(20, 10, false)
    val options = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<ProjectEntity>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .setQuery(query, config, ProjectEntity::class.java)
        .build()

    allProjectListAdapter.updateOptions(options)
    allProjectListAdapter.startListening()
    binding.recyclerHomeInvestorAllProjects.adapter = allProjectListAdapter
}
```

i asked to chatgp but it couldnt adapt it because has a older version of algolia so it doesnt work here is what i have so far

```
private suspend fun filterAllProjectsByFoneticSearch() {   
 val foneticSearch = binding.searchViewHomeInvestor.query.toString()
    val index = client.initIndex(IndexName("ideas"))

    // Realiza la búsqueda en Algolia
    val searchResults = index.search(com.algolia.search.model.search.Query(foneticSearch))

    // Procesa los resultados
    val hits = searchResults.hits
    val projectEntities = mutableListOf<ProjectEntity>()

    for (hit in hits) {
        val title = hit.get("title")
        // Ajusta esta parte según tu modelo
    }

    // Actualiza la lista de proyectos
    val updatedOptions = FirestorePagingOptions.Builder<ProjectEntity>()
        .setLifecycleOwner(this)
        .build()

    allProjectListAdapter.updateOptions(updatedOptions)
    binding.recyclerHomeInvestorAllProjects.adapter = allProjectListAdapter
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.
What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?